# fcitx tray icon does not change after swapping input methods

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After installed fcitx and googlepinyin on Pop OS 18.04, I found that the fcitx tray icon does not change when I switch between different input methods. It is always the same default keyboard icon.

```
ls /usr/share/fcitx/imicon
```

shows a list of icons existing in the directory.

Any suggestions to this problem would be greatly appreciated!